Will cashflow in my bank statement affected by second application?
During my first application (August), I provided a bank certificate with a balance amounting to £6000.
This application was rejected due to them needing the transaction details (i.e. a bank statement). I admit this was an oversight on my part since my japanese bank does not provide an english bank statement which takes 2 weeks + 1 week translation. I gathered it will be OK to just use a bank certificate
The problem is just after getting the bank certificate (snapshot) I needed to use the money to pay a downpayment for a house in my home country. During this time as well, i borrowed money from a friend to pad the payment which I ultimately didnt need so I returned the money after remitting the needed amount.
TLDR:
First application: created £6000 bank certificate. a week after remit £3000, return £3000
Second application: Bank statement shows above red flag transactions

In my upcoming second application, will this transaction be seen as funds parking or worse, deception and fraudulent?
My plan B is to change banks (bank that has english bank statements), then wait 3 months to provide a 3 month bank statement.
Edit: Adding details with my financial situation.

Monthly income £1500
Gross monthly is around £750 (after all expenses paid)

Planned initial visit was on November 1-8, which would have given me around ~£1500 spending money during the trip.

In 2019 I translated myself my bank statement and cash flow details for 6-month UK visa. I see your main problem is not with language, but just wanted to note the language is not necessary a hurdle. As it was explained to me - for short 6-moth UK visa you can translate your documents to English yourself and submit both the documents and their translations. I got my visa without additional requests from UK authorities.


The problem is just after getting the bank certificate (snapshot) I needed to use the money to pay a downpayment for a house in my home country. During this time as well, i borrowed money from a friend to pad the payment which I ultimately didnt need so I returned the money after remitting the needed amount.

So... you don't have the money. Telling the truth would be admitting to basically trying to lie, why did you borrow money to begin with then? Lying will be... worse? Either way, the consulate will see that you don't actually have the money you said you have. Which is exactly why they insist on full statements.
You'll need to wait until you get a clear statement showing the funds without any monkey business. Sounds like you're going to have to put off the trip for the next several months.

Fair enough. Regarding the Plan B. Would that bank statement be enough? Though since my salary will still go to the old bank account. The transactions in the new bank account will still show that it is coming from me (depositing from myself to myself) the amount to be transferred will be the same as my payslip

What would be the point?  Either way you'll need to wait for several months, noone will want a statement from an account you opened yesterday with a single deposit. They will probably ask about your income and would be suspicious if it doesn't show up in the statements. I don't see how this plan helps you.

I will not provide a bank statement with a single deposit. I plan to restart my application after 3 months to at least get 3 months worth of deposits.
My question is if it is ok that the transactions all come from me (salary account to savings account)
The point of creating the separate savings account is because my old account does not provide english bank statements. To lessen the hassle of translation I will use statements from this account instead

You already have one rejection due to insufficient financial information. If you reapply, you need to present a squeaky clean application, typically that means 6 months’ bank statements (not just 3), and your salary slips for said period. UKVI will want to see the statement for your salary and your savings account. Giving them just your savings account won’t work IMHO, even with salary slips.
